# при попытке установить discord.py появляется ошибка что делать

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

хочу установить discord.py но выходят следующие ошибки
1: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
2: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
3: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Если код Ваш, проверьте, пожалуйста, этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309865/python-list-object-has-no-attribute-read).